# Git client usage by operating system - what are the percentages?

Tags: windows, linux, git, macos

Just curious if anyone knows what the amount of Git usage by OS is? For clients.

This is a total guess - Linux 60%, Windows 25%, OSX 15%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are regular git surveys, with the last one in 2010. Here is an excerpt:

- [09. On which operating system(s) do you use Git?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSurvey2010#09._On_which_operating_system.28s.29_do_you_use_Git.3F)

  ```
  GNU/Linux    7243                               84.8%   
  BSD (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, etc.)     639     7.5% 
  MacOS X (Darwin)     3932                       46.0%  
  MS Windows/Cygwin    823                         9.6%   
  MS Windows/msysGit (MINGW)   2151               25.2%  
  other Unix   211                                 2.5%
  ```

Comment: Thats a reasonable answer. However, the number of downloads for the msysGit client suggests most people don't do the survey. There are 109000 downloads of msysGit since Feb 2011 with about 19000 for the Mac version. However, MacOS may we provide it via another package distribution mechanism than the googlecode site. Basically - you can't tell.

Comment: Thanks - I thought my OSX estimate was on the low side.